# Another SSH Tunneling question

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel, tunneling

Here's the Diagram

Server A ----> Server B <----- Laptop

So basically Server A and Laptop can connect to Server B directly but you can't establish a connection from Server A to Laptop directly, so we setup a reverse ssh tunnel from Server A to Server B so that Laptop can connect to Server A thru a tunnel setup by Server A. So right now ssh to Server A from Laptop is solved.

Now, I have an app setup in Server A that I need to access thru port 443 on the Laptop, how can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

A bit of a guess what you have already:

start with the reverse tunnel:

```
serverA:~ $ ssh -R 22:localhost:10022 serverB
```

then from the Laptop connect to serverB too and connect a local forward to the port you defined in the reverse forward:

```
laptop:~ $ ssh -L 10023:localhost:10022 serverB
```

if I understood you correctly something like that is the part you already did. And now to the last part:

connect to localhost on the port you used in the local forward, this sends all the packages directly to serverA, specify another port forward so your application can connect to serverA

```
laptop:~ $ ssh -p 10023 -L 10443:localhost:443 localhost
```

if your Application needs to connect to 443 and can't used another port as for example 10443 which I used in the example you'll have to do the last connection as root:

```
laptop:~ $ su -
laptop:~ # ssh -p 10023 -L 443:localhost:443 user@localhost
```

or

```
laptop:~ $ sudo ssh -p 10023 -L 443:localhost:443 user@localhost
```

Some explanations:

- "443:localhost:443" gets resolved at the remote end.... so it's actually serverA
- "user@" is the user needed to login to serverA, if not needed before its needed now as you locally are root now
- "localhost" is resolved locally so it's actually the Laptop.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the -R forwarded port on server B to be reachable from server A, you need to specify a bind-address on server B to the left of the remote port. E.g., if B has the address 1.2.3.4 and you are connecting from the laptop:

```
laptop:~ $ ssh -R 1.2.3.4:10443:127.0.0.1:443 server-b
```

This will forward port 10443 on server-b to 443 on the laptop. If you want to use port 443 instead, logon to server-b as root.

Comment: right now Server A is doing a reverse tunnel to Server B, so in Server B i can access Server A thru ssh on port 10222, how do I connect directly to Server A from my Laptop using that setup?

Answer (score 0):

If you have SSH access to Server A, then do something like ssh -L 8443:localhost:443 user@serverA should work. Then you can use https://localhost:8443 to connect.

Comment: I have no direct connection to Serer A from Laptop that's why we setup a reverse tunnel from Server A to Server B

Comment: After setting up the tunnel to A, you do the one above.